# Twillio SMS not getting sent from Django python project

Tags: python, django, twilio

Twilio SMS not getting sent from Django python project

I attempted to replicate the steps in blow article and send SMS using Twilio API

https://www.twilio.com/blog/broadcast-sms-text-messages-python-3-django

I keep geting

```
HTTP/1.1" 401 16
```

printed to the console

see my view method below

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, renderer_classes
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer, TemplateHTMLRenderer
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponse
from twilio.rest import Client


@api_view(('POST',))
@renderer_classes((TemplateHTMLRenderer, JSONRenderer))
def SendPhoneCodeView(request):
    print('phone is')
    phone = request.data.get('phone')
    print(phone)
    message_to_broadcast = ("This is Me Testing the incredible Twilio SMS "
                            "Not received yet? Wait for A Moment")
    client = Client(settings.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, settings.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN)
    client.messages.create(to=phone,
                           from_=settings.TWILIO_NUMBER,
                           body=message_to_broadcast)
    return HttpResponse("messages sent!", 200)
```

Also, all the print statements are NOT getting printed to console

Can someone please advise me on what exactly I am doing wrong and how to resolve this

Thanks

Comment: theres no curl request, i am using twilio api

Comment: `401` is an `Unauthorized Error`. Please check if you are passing proper authentication header while doing django API request.

Comment: It seems that perhaps your application is expecting some authentication before it will respond to this action. How are you making the request to this endpoint? Is it in a part of the application that requires authentication?

Comment: thanks the issue is fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

settings.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, settings.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN values were not getting passed